# How to create a stored procedure with dynamically created IN set

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have some SQL that I am converting to stored procedures via blind requirement/request.  There is a bit of SQL in the application I'm looking at that builds the where clause with a dynamic IN (set) statement.  I have searched for dynamic stored procedure but nothing close to what I'm looking for has come up for me.  Here is a sample of the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE Var.A = @Param AND Var.Id IN
```

From here the SQL is built manually using a string builder and then executed.  Not sure how I'd convert this into a stored procedure as I'm fairly new to them.

We are using C# and SQL Server

Comment: How about sending a user-defined table type from C# to the proc?

Comment: That sounds nice.  But I don't know what that means.  I will research this angle.  Thank you lol

Comment: @Matt1776: Depending on various factors, an IN clause can be anything from benign to pathologically bad re performance. As the point of the IN clause is to filter the returned rows, which is an INNER JOIN clause also does (in addition to bringing in extra columns), it is always sufficient and often better to perform an INNER JOIN instead of an IN. (Recall: an INNER JOIN returns only the rows with matching join fields in BOTH tables.)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I like your thinking - however as SQL isn't my main specialty - how would I use an inner join to specify a list of values? The query is doing a lookup where the ID is equal to a dynamic list of IDs.  There is no other way to specify the desired result afaik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an user-defined data type.

On the C# side it would look like this:

```
//Setup a DataTable with the same structure as the SQL Type
var data = new DataTable();
data.Columns.Add("value", typeof(string));

//Populate the table
data.Rows.Add("oneID");
data.Rows.Add("anotherID");

//You create your sql command
cmd.Parameters.Add("@listArgument", data);
//Command execution
```

On the SQL side you could have a type like this

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[NVarCharTable] AS TABLE (
    [value] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL);
```

And then the Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProc] 
    @listArgument NVarCharTable READONLY
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM FOO
    WHERE Var.Id IN (Select [value] FROM @listArgument)

END
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters

Comment: That ... is beautiful.  This seems akin to creating a temporary view but this is called a user defined table type instead?  I will see if this works!

Comment: I've added a reference link to read, I use DataTables but there are many ways to use it from C#

Comment: I am having a hell of a time getting this to work to be honest - It is definitely due to my lack of experience with this approach.  When I execute the stored proc in SQL Server how do I set the value of the [NVarCharTable]?  It only gives me a window interface where I cannot write SQL

Comment: @Matt1776 no worries. I've improved the example. Basically you need a DataTable with the same structure as the SQL Table type, you populate it like a normal DataTable (well it's a normal DataTable) and then you add it in the SQL parameter

Comment: Aw man turns out everything was fine I just copied the SQL wrong into the stored procedure create statement.  This is working beautifully!  Thank you!  Knowing my luck the client will come back and say I can't use user defined table types but I'll cross that bridge when I get there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQl SERVER 2016 or above you can use the string_split function to convert the csv params into table and then use it in your IN list

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE Var.A = @Param AND Var.Id IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@inlist, ','))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Alas, we are locked down to SQLServer 2012, but that looks like a valid, much simpler option as the split returns a table.  It would be nice to try that.

Comment: There are so many functions out there that take a list of values and split into a table.  Just Google it - sql server central has at least 3 versions.  So this approach is also feasible in other versions with just the addition of 1 function.

Comment: @Jesse after some cursory research I've only found a way whereby you create a function that calls a dll - do you have anything specific in mind?  After perusing the SQLServer documentation I did not see anything I could use that wouldn't be too onerous.

Comment: Sure here are a couple: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/SUBSTRING/124330/  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Miscellaneous/31913/

Comment: Wow that is some advanced SQL-ing going on there, that may be what I need to use if user defined table types are not allowed.  Thank you.  You should probably add that as an answer so everyone benefits from the citation :)

Comment: I added it as an answer.  That second one might be slower than the first link but it takes less effort to add to the database.  The other one uses a numbers table but doesn't seem to create it.  BTW, the search I used is Split String t-sql function.

Answer (score 1):

To piggy back off of @lostmylogin, you can pass in a parameter delimited and use one of these SQL functions to parse it into a table:

http://sqlservercentral.com/scripts/SUBSTRING/124330 
or
http://sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Miscellaneous/31913